# jquery toggle on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery hover.

It's a div in a div, the div with the hover is called .flip and the div which expands is called .panel.

The hover bugs, when I go over .flip expands .panel. But panel is in the div .flip so the hovering flip will be as big as .flip + the size of .panel. And .flip has to be as width as .panel what i don't want..

I know that its possible to let .panel out of .flip but it has to stay in there. Else all the .panel's will expand when i hover over one of the 5 .flip's. So I have to use $this.

The second problem is, that when i go 2, 3, 4 or more times over the .flip, .panel will expand 2, 3, 4 or more times and that looks laggy.

Can you help me? I know nothing about jquery, so I even don't know where to search for.

Code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".flip").hover(function(){
         $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("slow"); 
    });
}); 
</script>
```

css:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.flip{
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color:white;
     width:490px;
    margin-left: 43px;
    color:#1667b2;
    text-align:center;
    border-top; 2px #1667b2 solid
    display:block;
}

.panel
{
    width:490px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#1667b2;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    display:none;
    padding:5px;
}

#meerreferenties {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}

</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="flip">Klik hier voor meer informatie.
    <div class="panel">Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bTL5/

Answer (score 1):

Use [.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )](http://api.jquery.com/stop/#stop-clearQueue-jumpToEnd)

```
$(this).find(".panel").stop(true,true).slideToggle("slow");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bTL5/1/

Comment: ty for the fiddle link V31

Comment: Same problem, but then its flashing. If you hover over .flip and then while expanding go off it and then go on .panel.

Comment: Yes, but we have thousands of views per day, and i think that more then 50% use another browser then IE :P